# JSON data receive bad format over MQTT python

Tags: python, json, mqtt

I have a problem with receiving data over MQTT in Python.

I send from one script:

```
payload = '{"sensor":[{"name":"temp","value":"%s"}]}' % str(read_temp())
print payload
print is_json(payload) 
client.publish("xxxxx/xxxxx", json.dumps(payload))
```

and receive with another script:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    message = str(msg.payload)
    if is_json(message): 
        jsonResponse=json.loads(json.dumps(message))
        print jsonResponse
```

Output:

```
"{\"sensor\":[{\"name\":\"temp\",\"value\":\"23.0\"}]}"
```

I try play with loads and dumps but nothing helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You double escaping the message, once at publish time and once when it's received with `json.dumps`. Remove the extra from the subscriber:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    message = str(msg.payload)
    if is_json(message): 
        jsonResponse=json.loads(message)
        print jsonResponse
```